# Проверка пользователя на каждой страничке сайта

Tags: php, авторизация

Добрый день.
Ситуация - есть личный кабинет пользователя, доступ в личный кабинет организован после авторизации через сессию. Подскажите необходимо ли проверять на каждой страничке личного кабинета данные из сессии с данными в БД по этому пользователю(например сравниваю по hash -логина и пароля) или достаточно проверить на существование некоторых переменных ключевых из сессии и не делать запросов ?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, сессия - это та штука, которая активируется для каждого уникального сеанса связи пользователя с сервером. Авторизация проходит один раз, и при удачной проверке логина/пароля, идентификатор пользователя записывается в переменную сессии взамен дефолтного гостевого. А дальше, при каждом переходе с одной страницы на другую, сервер читает этот самый идентификатор из сессионной переменной, и что-то в связи с этим делает. Например, проверят возможность доступ этого пользователя к тем или иным страницам.

В отдельных случаях, для безопасности, в сессию пишется клиентский IP последнего обращения к серверу. Чтобы при следующей проверке иметь возможность обнаружить его изменение и сбросить авторизацию. Например, на случай если правдами-неправдами кука сессии ушла на сторону.

Answer (score 0):

Проверяй Сессию, она уникальна и читается только сервером

Comment: в смысле проверить существование сессии вообще ? об этом речь ?

Comment: при авторизации например записывай ид пользователя в базе в$_SESSION['id']. А потом везде проверяй наличие  $_SESSION['id']